# SKSpriteNode showing non integer position when assigned an SKPhysicsBody

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have some very simple Swift code which places an SKSpriteNode on screen at position x:214, y:200. In the update method, I print the current position of said SKSpriteNode. If I omit all of the SKPhysicsBody code, then the position of my SKSpriteNode is shown in the debug window as (214.0, 200.0) which is as I would expect it. If, however, I run the program with the SKPhysicsBody code present, then the first print returns correct with (214.0, 200.0), but subsequent calls return (214.000015258789, 200.0).

This looks to me like something in the physics world is affecting (albeit in a very small way) the position of the SKSpriteNode. What I cannot fathom for the life of me is what that could be. My code is exactly as shown below, nothing more and nothing less. I think I have disabled everything that could possibly have any effect on the position. I am just hoping that I might have missed something silly.

The problem may seem trivial as the values are only fractionally off, however when I attempt to move the sprite smoothly across the screen (incrementing it's x position + 1 on each update) then it will occasionally miss an entire position, going from 289.0 to 289.99, then 291.0.

Any help would be much appreciated. It feels like a bug to me, but as I am fairly new to the physics side of SpriteKit, I would like to be certain.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

private var playerSprite   : SKSpriteNode!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)//borderBody
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    playerSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    playerSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 214, y: 200)

    playerSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

    if let playerSpritePhysicsObject = playerSprite.physicsBody {
        playerSpritePhysicsObject.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        playerSpritePhysicsObject.affectedByGravity = false
        playerSpritePhysicsObject.allowsRotation = false
        playerSpritePhysicsObject.dynamic = false
        playerSpritePhysicsObject.angularVelocity = 0.0
        playerSpritePhysicsObject.friction = 0.0
        playerSpritePhysicsObject.linearDamping = 0.0
        playerSpritePhysicsObject.angularDamping = 0.0
        playerSpritePhysicsObject.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        playerSpritePhysicsObject.restitution = 0.0
    }
    self.addChild(playerSprite)
}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    print("playerSprite Position = \(playerSprite.position)")
}
}
```

Here is the debug window output:

```
playerSprite Position = (214.0, 200.0)
2017-06-19 20:39:47.682 PhysicsTest[9193:2340365] <SKMetalLayer: 0x14fe6e760>: calling -display has no effect.
playerSprite Position = (214.000015258789, 200.0)
playerSprite Position = (214.000030517578, 200.0)
playerSprite Position = (214.000030517578, 200.0)
playerSprite Position = (214.000030517578, 200.0)
playerSprite Position = (214.000030517578, 200.0)
```

Comment: After days of searching, I finally found someone with a similar problem. Unfortunately they didn't appear to find a resolution either. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236737/adding-physics-body-to-sprite-in-spritekit-alters-its-position-fractionally

Comment: I have also found this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27057 which although not exactly the same as my problem, as my SKSpriteNode isn't within an SKNode object. Does appear to suggest this might be an ongoing bug from over 2 years ago.

Comment: I have added a work around to my code which does indeed appear to resolve the issue. It's nasty but effective. As we can assume that the problem lies within the physics engine and its placement of SKSpriteNode's, you can force the sprite into its correct place by setting its position again in the didFinishUpdate() func.

Comment: do not go off of what the debug log says, it can be wrong from time to time.  Do an actual comparison print(position.x == 214)

Comment: After the first '2 print', the position is constant. I think that what is happening i that you place your sprite, assign the position and then print it in `update()`. Then the physics functions of the game loop run and the position is altered slightly on the next 2 iterations, according to some internal processing. Then, on subsequent game loops, the position doesn't change.

Comment: If you update the spite's position by a fixed amount in each call to update(), you *will* get erratic movement. `update()` is not called exactly every 1/60th of a second - you will need to use the time interval passed to update() and the desired speed of the sprite in points/sec to update the sprite's position. I think your problem will be largely academic.

Comment: Steve, updating my sprites position by 1pt each update has and always does work just fine, obviously assuming the game always manages 60fps. The problem only occurs when you attach a physicsBody. The physics engine just seems to add some drift to the positioning of sprites, even when there are no objects in the scene acting against it.

Comment: The only reason the 214.000015258789 remains constant in my example above is because I removed the line which moved the sprite. If you move the sprite then the variance (drift) changes with each position. You might get 215.0 then 216.000000333 then 217.0 then 218.0 and then 219.00000177 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time agonising over this problem, I think I may have found a work around. It's nasty but does the trick. Simply reset the position of the SKSpriteNode in the didFinishUpdate() function which occurs after the didSimulatePhysics() function has complete.

```
override func didFinishUpdate() {
    playerSprite.position.x = 214
}
```

Having tested further, I found this didn't work for iOS 7.1. In order for it work on older devices, you must place the code in the  didSimulatePhysics() function instead:

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    playerSprite.position.x = 214
}
```